# Where do i put string to write .txt in createfile?

Tags: java, android, string, file, text

Heres my code for create file, it works but string is blank. Where do i put string for a .txt file?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.
ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT); 
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("application/txt");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "invoice.txt");
startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_FILE);
```

Comment: What language are you using? You can add the language as a tag to help people find your question.

Comment: Java thanks will do

Comment: You need to get the `Uri` via `onActivityResult()`, use `openOutputStream()` on `ContentResolver` to get an `OutputStream` for that `Uri`, and write your string to that `OutputStream`. Note that `startActivityForResult()` is deprecated; Google wants you to use `ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument` instead. I demonstrate this in [this sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/vFINAL/ContentEditor), covered in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-files-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/).

Comment: Thanks mam, yeah i just figured it out didnt know about the  Contracts though. By the way  ive seen other apps at sdk 30 save to my files without permission or grant, to specific files how are they doing this?